# How to send multiple modified messages to one endpoint in camel?

Tags: apache-camel

in my application I query a service based on a given data structure for some identification numbers. For each returned identification number I want to sent a mail message based on the query data enriched with the identification number to the same recipient:

```
from("direct:querySource")
.enrich("direct:executeQueryIds", new IdWithDataAggregator())
// here I stuck - want to send the original received message from 
// the querySource n (executeQueryIds) times enrich by iterating
// over executeQueryIds result
.to("smtp://...")
.end()
```

I tried to split up the messages using a `split` based on a certain message header, but inside the split I obtian only the splitted header value as body, not the original message. Using the `split` call with an aggregator as second parameter neither worked well, because the second exchange was `null`.

I also experimented with `loop` constructs, but I feel there should be a more convenient and idomatic way of doing it.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to turn a single message into multiple messages you would still want to use a splitter. You would probably want to do something like this:

```
from(START)
 .split(). method(SplitBean.class, "splitMessage")
 .to(FINISH);
```

You can pass in headers into the bean method and manually split the messages that way.

Comment: Thanks, that worked very well - I believe I have got the idea now. Annotated my split method with the appropriate Handler, Header and Body annotations.